# Create tiled clones in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I have a circle and want to create six tiled clones (wedges/triangles) around the circle, each rotated by 60 degree. So I tried it as following:

- Select the triangle.
- Shift the triangle's center to the circles center.
- While having only the triangle selected go to:
- Edit / Clone / Create_Tiled_Clones
- In tab "Symmetry" select: P1_simple_translation
- In tab "Shift" change: Shift_X: Per_column: -100%
- In tab "Rotation" change: Angle: Per_column: 60°
- In the lower (light gray) window of "Create_Tiled_Clones" change:
- Rows, columns 1 x 6
  (because 6 columns (triangles) times 60 degree creates an evenly arranged circle)

However as you can see in the image it does not clone the triangles around the intended center.
Does someone see the problem? Thanks in advance!

[image: createing tiled clone in inkscape]

---

**Desired output:**
(Which I was able to achieve with a little workaround by: `Object/Transform/Rotate/Angle: 60°` However in case i am having not only 6 items like in my case, but 100 items, this way would be very uncomfortable ... )

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the rotation center of an object before you use the tiled clones dialog. Just select the object, then click a second time on it to enter rotation mode. Grab the center and move it to the place where you want it.

In the tiled clones dialog, make sure the object doesn't move in x or y direction, but stays in place with only rotation. You can achieve this by moving by -100% y/x per row/column.

However, if all you want to create is a star (as the images suggest), use the star tool for it.

Comment: The -100% was what did it for me. Thanks.